# Pass value of one dropdown to another using Multiple jquery .ajax() calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I'm not much familiar with jquery, but here I'm trying to do this :

I'm trying to pass value of one dropdown to another dropdown, here is the jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    import="java.sql.*,com.connection.DBConnection;"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Country</title>
<style>
.formContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #75D1FF;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
} 
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Country.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="formContainer">
        <form action="SampleServlet" method="get">
            <fieldset>
                <label>Country :</label> <select id="countryid" name="country">
                    <option value='select'>Select</option>
                    <%
                        Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection();
                        Statement st = con.createStatement();
                        String sql = "select * from country";
                        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                        while (rs.next()) {
                    %>
                    <option value='<%=rs.getString(2)%>'><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>
                    <%
                        }
                        rs.close();
                    %>
                </select><br />

                <div class="Stateselect">
                <select id="Stateid">
                </select>       
                </div><br /><br />

                <div class="Cityselect">
                <select id="Cityid" onchange="loadXMLDoc()">
                </select>
                </div><br /><br />

                <div class="Areaselect">
                <select id="Areaid"></select>
                </div><br /><br />

                <div class="buttonsDiv">
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, depending on the country I select, states should be displayed, depending on states the cities and from cities, the areas in it. I've used three servlet classes here namely CountryServlet, StateServlet and CityServlet Here is the js file I'm using :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Stateselect,.Cityselect,.Areaselect").hide();
    $("#countryid").change(function() {
        var country = document
        .getElementById("countryid").value;
        if (country != 'select') {
            $.ajax({

                url : "ActionServlet?country="+ country,
                method : "GET",
                type : "html",
                success : function(
                        result) {
                    $(".Stateselect").html(result);
                    $(".Stateselect").show(700);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(".Stateselect").hide(700);
        };
    });

    if(document.getElementById("Stateid").style.display != "none")
    {
        $('#Stateid').change(function() {
            var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
            var state = document.getElementById("Stateid").value;
            if (country != 'select' && state != null) {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "StateServlet?country="+ country+ "&state="+ state,
                    method : "GET",
                    type : "html",
                    success : function(result) {
                        $(".Cityselect").html(result);
                        $(".Cityselect").show(700);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $(".Cityselect").hide(700);
            };
        });
    }

    if(document.getElementById("Cityid").style.display != "none") {
        $('#Cityid').change(function() {
            var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
            var state = document.getElementById("Stateid").value;
            var city = document.getElementById("Cityid").value;
            if ((country != 'select' && state != 'select') && city != 'select') {
                $.ajax({
                    url : "CityServlet?country="+ country + "&state=" + state + "&city="+ city,
                    // SampleServlet?country=India&state=Telangana&city=Hyderabad&area=Madhapur
                    method : "GET",
                    type : "html",
                    success : function(result) {
                        $(".Areaselect").html(result);
                        $(".Areaselect").show(700);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $(".Areaselect").hide(700);
            };
        });
    }; 
});
```

Problem is, only the first ajax call is working. Rest two are not. Please help. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You hid all the divs with dropdowns, at the first line of your js code

```
$(".Stateselect,.Cityselect,.Areaselect").hide();
```

and then you are binding the change event based on the fact if the div is hidden or not.

```
if(document.getElementById("Cityid").style.display != "none") {
}
```

Since the divs are hidden, the code doesn't get executed and the change event doesn't register. 
 I recommend revisiting the if conditions where you have tested the display property like  `if(document.getElementById("Cityid").style.display != "none")` remove these and the code will work.

Update:

Since you need to run the code only if the div is visible, you have to change the following

```
if(document.getElementById("Cityid").style.display != "none") {
        $('#Cityid').change(function() {
```

into

```
$('#Cityid').change(function() {
  if(document.getElementById("Cityid").style.display != "none") {
```

this way, the change event is always bound but the code only gets executed if the div is visible.

Complete code for one dropdown

```
$('#Cityid').change(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("Cityid").style.display != "none") {
        var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
        var state = document.getElementById("Stateid").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("Cityid").value;
        if ((country != 'select' && state != 'select') && city != 'select') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "CityServlet?country=" + country + "&state=" + state + "&city=" + city,
                // SampleServlet?country=India&state=Telangana&city=Hyderabad&area=Madhapur
                method: "GET",
                type: "html",
                success: function (result) {
                    $(".Areaselect").html(result);
                    $(".Areaselect").show(700);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $(".Areaselect").hide(700);
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: That is the point. When the country dropdown changes, state dropdown is displayed. If the display style is not none, then only the code should work.

Comment: @Karthik are u doing any mistake in ids in `Stateselect, stateid` or `Cityselect, cityid`.... etc. You hide all class(`.Stateselect,.Cityselect,.Areaselect`) and comparing with ids(`Stateid....etc`)